# What is the better way of getting API data, rendering it and in general working with it

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, api

I am working a lot with API data in my Django applications lately. I have written some APIs and I am trying to get a better understanding of best practices. So as I understand it, I can get my API data in two ways.

I can either get my data through my django view out of my database, turn it into JSON format with json.dumps, pass it to my template, save it into a javascript variable and from there pass it to my .js file where I can use it as I please.

Alternatively, I think I can make an API call from my .js file and get the data directly from my API without taking the road through my database.

But what is better in regards to performance and especially security? The way I imagine it is that the second way (js-way) might be better in terms of performance whereas using the database-approach might be safer?

I simply do not know.

Let's for instance assume I have an API that I only want to use internally without public access. What would be the way to go?

Or let's say I have a public API. Does that change the equation?

To summarize it: What is the best way of working with API-data? Maybe there are also ways I don't know about?

EDIT: Let me be clearer: I am using Django REST framework to provide data. I am looking for the best way to work with this data that I am providing through the REST framework. Let's say I have data like this through REST:

```
[
    {
        "user": "testuser",
        "project": "testproject",
        ...
    }
]
```

How do I best work with this data to manipulate, visualize, play around with it. Getting it from the database in my view and pass it to a template, pass it again to a javascript file?

Or make a direct json call with Javascript getting it into my js file? Or does it depend?

Any comments, opinions or answers are very much appreciated. Thanks for the help and interest

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-rest-framework for API.

[Django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

**If Why?**

Django REST Framework. Django REST framework is a powerful and flexible toolkit for building Web APIs. The Web-browsable API is a huge usability win for your developers. Authentication policies including packages for OAuth1a and OAuth2. Serialization that supports both ORM and non-ORM data sources.

Comment: thanks my friend. But let me clarify: I do use Django REST Framework. It's fantastic. What I am asking is: What is the best way to work with the data provided **through** the REST framework. I edited my question to be more clear

Comment: @Micromegas Django REST Framework API provides JSON format data. JSON data are supported web example: AJAX call and android for API etc.